# Can someone help explain how a setTimeout within a for loop works? Does this have anything to do with closure

Tags: javascript

```
var result = 0;

for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += i;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Why will result equal 9 and not 3 at the end of this?

Comment: 1+(2+1)+(3+2+1) = 9

Comment: This spawns 3 timeouts that will all finish at the same time.  You need to call them recursively as the previous finishes if you want them to act sequentially.

Comment: @zero298 no, that's not right. 1000 is how many milliseconds to delay the anonymous function call by.

Comment: @Griffin I edited as soon as I posted it.  The underlying point still remains.  You are making all the timeouts at once instead of as the previous finishes.

Comment: @zero298 sure, but you have no idea about OP's intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 9 because you are adding `result` to your loop counter `i` and both numbers increase upon each loop iteration. If you just want the final answer to be 3, then you don't need `result` at all and can just report the value of the loop counter upon the final iteration of the loop.

It's unclear what your goal is here, but often times people believe that a timer belongs in a loop when they want something done repeatedly. A timer can do that without any loops helping it via the `setInterval()` timer or a recursive `setTimeout()` timer. Both approaches are shown below:

**Recursive setTimeout() Timer:**

```js
var result = 0;

function timerCallback(){
  if(result < 3){
    console.log(++result);
    // A second timer is embedded in the
    // first timer's callback function.
    // This second timer calls the current
    // function, setting up a looping flow.
    setTimeout(timerCallback, 1000);
  }
}

// Start a one time timer
setTimeout(timerCallback, 1000);
```

**setInterval() Timer:**

```js
var timer = null; // Will hold reference to timer's id
var result = 0;

function timerCallback(){
  if(result < 3){
    console.log(++result);
  } else {
    // Cancel timer
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

// Start a timer that continues
// until it is stopped.
timer = setInterval(timerCallback, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote

```
var result = 0;

for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += i;
  }, 1000);
}
```

beacause of javascript variable hoisting it became

```
var result = 0;
var i;

for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += i;
  }, 1000);
}
```

`var i` moves to the top.

---

And since javascript is non-blocking all the asynchronous code like `setTimeout` in your case will execute after there is no more blocking operation in the call stack i.e. after the loop ends.

---

When the loop ends the value of `i is 3` and there when `result += 3` is executed 3 times result becomes 9

---

But if you wanted it to be what I can see from the question this below

```
result += 0;
result += 1;
result += 2;
```

**result 3**

then you can achieve it through `closure`

```js
var result = 0;
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  const j = i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    result += j;
    console.log(result);
  }, 1000);
}
```

the end result will be 3 in this case

---

What happens here is that `j` declared will have the closure over the value of i, in every loop iteration, and setTimeout of each iteration will remember their value of j that was attached at the time of iteration.

Hope this helps